# Vertically center content of ListItem in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listitem

I have a layouting problem with my android application:

I have a Listview consiting of items which are using the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="40px"
android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"  android:textSize="20px"       android:id="@+id/track_position" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/track_name"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:paddingLeft="8dip"
  android:textSize="14px"
/>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/track_artist"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:paddingLeft="8dip"
  android:textSize="8px"

/>
```

This comes up with the following result:
[image]

But i would like to have the tracks title and subtitle centered as well. like that:
[image]

So AFAIK i did everything so that this would be the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

On the LinearLayout containing the two textViews, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="40px"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:id="@+id/track_position"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/track_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:textSize="14px" />
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/track_artist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:textSize="8px" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! I will test that today. So gravity describes how the content should be aligned and layout_gravity how the element should be aligned in the parent?

Comment: Yay that one did it! It was less affort to change than the relative layout. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for the track_position TextView.

**EDIT:** In light of Maaalte correctly pointing out that the above is for RelativeLayout, I found my layout I was thinking of which achieves what is needed...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_time_short"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_time_short"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_time_short"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my case, this is a TV Guide entry and the lefthand TextView shows time (HH:mm) with the TV show's title and description to the right. Everything centres fine for me.

Comment: I think that is for RelativeLayout

Comment: Ah okay i'll check that later. Is it just a matter of taste to choose between Linear and Relative Layout or is one of the both ways "Better" or has "better performance" or does one way reacts diffrently on Changes like rotating the phone to landscape?

Comment: @Chris: I'd tried with LinearLayout but had similar problems to you. Perhaps I could have made it work if I'd spent more time. I came across a complex list item in an example using RelativeLayout and gave it a try - it pretty much worked first time with a few minor mods so I stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this, just web styling. But if there is always 1 line for the track and the band, can't you just set a paddingTop value to the second LinearLayout block?

Comment: This would be an option but I'm planning to leave the height of the items to the theme so i don't know how high the item will be. And i can't understand why this works for the textview but not for the second linearlayout.